# Problems with the route-controller model in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller

I am having a problem creating a driver for my route. For some reason it does not recognize the `send()` property.

This is the code of my route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Ctrl = require('../controllers/index');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', Ctrl.list());

module.exports = router;
```

And this is the code of my controller:

```
const express = require('express');

Ctrl = {}

Ctrl.list = (req, res) => {
   res.send("sended");
}

module.exports = Ctrl;
```

The same happens when I use traditional functions, which are not an arrow functions.

On the other hand, this is my express configuration where the configured routes are:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

const app = express();
require('./database/config');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(helmet());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

I am getting this error:

> E:\elarchivero\api\controllers\index.js:6    res.send("sended");
>          ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
>       at Object.Ctrl.list (E:\elarchivero\api\controllers\index.js:6:8)
>       at Object. (E:\elarchivero\api\routes\index.js:6:22)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>       at Object. (E:\elarchivero\api\app.js:7:21)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your router to a function reference rather than a call.

`router.get('/', Ctrl.list);`